# Editing _setting.scss in Compass

Tags: css, sass

So I'm finally starting to understand the power of Foundations mixed with Compass. Awesome stuff! Except I ran into a snag and I can't figure out why it keeps doing this...

I'm trying to change all my responsive class (small, medium, large) media queries in the _settings.scss from their original min-widths to max-width instead.

When I do this though Ruby is giving me some 'tude that goes something like this.

Change detected at 15:17:27 to: _settings.scss 
identical css/app.scss

I think because of this it is not actually making any of the changes(am I correct with that assumption)?

What did I do to mess it up, or am I just doing something that is not allowed to happen? I am using an additional stylesheet to perform these layouts(this whole thing is for my navbar) under _layout.scss, but yea.. I'm stuck. Please help :)

Comment: ? why is this getting voted down?

Answer (score 0):

its just commenting on the changes that happened. Its working as expected.

```
 Change detected at 12:57:58 to: _settings.scss
 identical static-dent/stylesheets/foundation-style/buttons.scss 
 identical static-dent/stylesheets/foundation-style/forms.css
```

in the example above, there are changes to _settings.scss and no changes to buttons.scss basically to let you know what has changed.

Comment: hmmm... the thing is that it is not changing the app.css file at all *i meant app.css instead of app.scss. when I look in the app.css file it hasn't changed either. the media queiries stay min-width still instead of max-width. i think it should say it's overwritten the file instead of saying its identical right?

Comment: `identical css/app.css` means no changes to app.css identical means no changes. working as expected. maybe your question should be something else

Comment: except that i am changing the _settings.scss which plugs into app.scss which means that their should be a change. so sure saying that it is identical and it not changing does make sense. but i am changing it and that is why i am confused.

Comment: oh ok now i get it! are you sure that settings.scss if being imported into app.scss? if so it should be at the top

Comment: great! and yep // Global Foundation Settings @import "settings"; are the first two lines I have in my app.scss.

Comment: now change the order of the imports per http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/1598-_settingsscss-gets-overridden